# Drag and drop within a text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to drop html element into a text at mouse pointer position, using JQuery?

I've been implementing song text editor (yet another...) with drag-and-drop guitar chord positioning. I would click a chord, drag it and drop *between lyrics letters*. Lyrics are contentEditable div.

My quick solution was surrounding each letter with a `<span class="letter">` tag and make entire song (letters + chords) sortable. Sortable has `cancel` attribute for `span.letter`, so you cannot move letters :-). But it implies maintaining this text structure while editing lyrics and seems not to be so efficient.

Can I achieve this in a more simple way, particularily without surrounding each letter with a tag?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this with sliders, one for each note.